# Search children of certain parent in XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a question regarding the processing of an XML file using DomDocument in PHP.

```
<managedObject class="class1" version="version1" distName="distName1" id="id1">
    <p name="a">Some data</p>
    <p name="b">Some data</p>
    <p name="c">Some data</p>
    <p name="d">Data I need</p>
    <p name="e">Some data</p>
</managedObject>

<managedObject class="class2" version="version2" distName="distName2" id="id2">
    <p name="a">Some data</p>
    <p name="b">Some data</p>
    <p name="c">Some data</p>
    <p name="d">Some data</p>
    <p name="e">Some data</p>
</managedObject>
```

For example, I need to get the data from the element with the name 'd' but only if it's parent has the class="class1", version="version1", etc.

So far I tried with:

```
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@distName, 'distName1')][contains(@class, 'class1')][contains(@version, 'version1')]/[contains(@name, 'd')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo " {$node->nodeValue}\n";
}
```

But it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to seach that `[contains(@name, 'd')]`? Everything:

```
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@distName, 'distName1')][contains(@class, 'class1')][contains(@version, 'version1')]/*[contains(@name, 'd')]");
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ use `*` for any item
```

Just `p`:

```
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@distName, 'distName1')][contains(@class, 'class1')][contains(@version, 'version1')]/p[contains(@name, 'd')]");
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ use `p` for `p` items only
```